# cloudfront streaming distribution cant access to my bucket files with signed url

Tags: java, amazon-cloudfront

I set a streaming distribution the same way I set my downloading distribution, i am using osmf player. And for some reasons I am not able to play my mp4 files I am testing.  So I tested a few things I took the Restrict Viewer Access in my distribution, and I was able to play my normal files, just adding the filename, and the files with a signedurl.  But when I put back my distribution with Restricted Viewer Access, for signed url only I cannot play them. 
I had an Identity attached to my cloudfront distribution E1XXXXXXXXXW, and this is my bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E1XXXXXXXXXW"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketXXXXXXXXXXXX/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But i can not access any of my files when I restrict "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E1XXXXXXXXXW"

**UPDATE**

So i did more tests, I created a downloading distribution and kept my streaming distribution, this is the code,

```
String signedUrlDownload = CloudFrontService.signUrl("http://" + distributionDomain + "/" + s3ObjectKey, // Resource
                                                                                                                    // URL or
                                                                                                                    // Path
                        keyPairId, // Certificate identifier, an active trusted
                                    // signer for the distribution
                        derPrivateKey, // DER Private key data
                        policy // Access control policy
                        );

                System.out.println(signedUrlDownload);

                signedUrl = CloudFrontService.signUrl(s3ObjectKey, // Resource
                                                                    // URL or
                                                                    // Path
                        keyPairId, // Certificate identifier, an active trusted
                                    // signer for the distribution
                        derPrivateKey, // DER Private key data
                        policy // Access control policy
                        );
                System.out.println(signedUrl);
```

So when I do this I am able to download my files with the string that comes out from signedUrlDownload.

So i know it is generated correctly.

So I kept doing tests and took off Restrict View Access, and tried again with a signed URL and it seems to work, but then I started to manually alter the url and it worked every time no matter what I do.
Everything works:

```
testfolder/myfile.m4a
testfolder/myfile.m4a?aaaaaa=xxxxxxxxx
testfolder/myfile.m4a??Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6IioiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjEzODA1OTg3NTN9LCJJcEFkZHJlc3MiOnsiQVdTOlNvdXJjZUlwIjoiMC4wLjAuMC8wIn0sIkRhdGVHcmVhdGVyVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxMzgwNTg3OTUzfX19XX0_&Signature=EzXX1h6iBFSb6Gx2LeFwOnFmvCl6flNMXYsEKwd7ZSSMWlcd-mtOXjBqvoP58M~Bj1kikbNSDaCX5j14TY6LjVtTXE7QgcGC~0c9~wxsDAnN8VYN8ItTDJySzwv8oLPrHc3O2hh6kGF7UH3T04qbhXplRdSgHZJePLHbfG70z6A_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAITVLU6K7B3YQB4HQ
```

So this tells me that my policies are not working correctly when I restrict access, or  maybe I am passing the wrong values to my player (I also tested on the cloudfront client diagnostic tool, http://d1k5ny0m6d4zlj.cloudfront.net/diag/CFStreamingDiag.html).

This is what I am doing on my client basically is passing the following stream:

```
rtmp://myasdfad.cloudfront.com/cfx/st/mp4:testfolder/myfiles.m4p?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6IioiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjEzODA1OTk5MjB9LCJJcEFkZHJlc3MiOnsiQVdTOlNvdXJjZUlwIjoiMC4wLjAuMC8wIn0sIkRhdGVHcmVhdGVyVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxMzgwNTg5MTIwfX19XX0_&Signature=jaw9KQybdckjvJBpJpeo-ukVEy9nerKsTpNAa3SJxrYkWzQG0CrF6hP1ok0iGW4wKvft4hhKzZhaO-OL7hVXE09ORzCxosDhYVPGvFoLKGNYH3mP4KXXxqlBxVcNeoUogRXqNI2SJW2J-TwQ-othwwRRas3pDaVfMddyrjBr2pU_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAITVLU6K7B3YQB4HQ
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong something was wrong with the initial time that is why it worked sometimes and sometime it didnt.